# How can I read parameter from uri with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, parameters, uri

I am quite new to to angular and most things and concepts are completely new for me.

I am working on a page that have a URL as follows:

```
http://domain/araneum/page/show/1
```

Is there any easy way to read the '1' from URL?
 What I was able to understand there are two ways:

1. Read it on backend and create JS variable to be used by angular (not sure if that is the best practices)
2. Pass the parameter as hash. in my case it is not that convenient, because this page is quite complex already and I wanted to have a separate application for it. Also, there are couple of validations that must happen on backend before page rendering.

Is there any other better approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend completing the AngularJs tutorial if you haven't already done so. In particular look at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Relevant code for you

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
  }]);
```

In this example the `phoneId` will be in place of `1` in your URL.

Comment: Well, route params have nothing to do with url, it rather deals with hash. How is it remotely relates to backend parsms?  And I did go through tutorial...